# [laravel][npm] I can't use css daterangepicker

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I install daterangepicker with npm and i can't use it

This command

```
npm install daterangepicker
```

this is my code

create.blade.php

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" name="period_date" required>    
$('input[name="period_date"]').daterangepicker();
```

app.js

```
 window.moment = require('moment');
window.daterangepicker = require('daterangepicker');
```

this is result

[image]

after click input daterangepicker
[image]
css is not working

[npm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daterangepicker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This my answer

in file ..\resources\sass\app.scss

should import .css

```
//Daterangepicker
@import "~daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css";
```

after import run

```
npm run dev
```

credit : [Medium](https://medium.com/@Oriechinedu/how-to-add-jquery-ui-plugin-to-a-laravel-app-using-laravel-mix-e85bf0244fc1)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery below the input field should be set between script tags. Example below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
</script>
```